# Что за память я читаю таким образом?

Tags: c#, .net

Предположим есть массив байт

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
```

и вот такая

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ByteToUlongConverter
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] bytes;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ulong[] ulongs;

    public ByteToUlongConverter(byte[] bytes)
    {
        this.ulongs = null;
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
}
```

структура.

Далее с помощью этой структуры я делаю

```
ByteToUlongConverter conv = new ByteToUlongConverter(bytes);

foreach (ulong ul in conv.ulongs)
    Console.WriteLine($"{ul:X16}");
```

При этом выводится что-то наподобие

```
0807060504030201
793C086C00000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000004710B40
00000001793BFDD8
793BED0C00000000
```

Т.е. выделял я 8 байт, а прочёл 64 (можно даже не только прочесть, но и записать что-то).

Вот эти дополнительные байты они чьи? Что это за память? Т.е. насколько я понимаю мой массив лежит где-то в куче, а это что-то, что лежит рядом. Куча в .Net как организована, она одна на все процессы или у каждого процесса своя куча? Т.е. может ли другой процесс без особых привилегий попытаться считать таким образом что-то в моём процессе?

Comment: Хм, на IdeOne воспроизводится: https://ideone.com/0CNmCS Бред какой-то, ладно бы это был unsafe-код...

Comment: Да, включение флага "Allow unsafe code" не требуется.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вы правы, это память из кучи, расположенная сразу за массивом байт. Куча в .NET одна на каждый application domain, или, условно говоря, одна на одно приложение. *Сборщик мусора* работает именно с кучей, и было бы не очень хорошо, если из-за соседнего приложения пришлось бы останавливать также и ваше приложение, чтобы освободить память.

Однако обратите внимание, что *процесс* и *домен приложения* — разные понятия. Процесс это структура ядра Windows, и внутри одного процесса может быть множество доменов приложения, потому что они (предположительно) управляемые — то есть не могут просто так залезть в память друг друга. Но, поскольку это один процесс Windows то *теоретически* они конечно могут испортить память друг друга, если используют неуправляемый код.

Поэтому .NET не разрешает просто так запускать неуправляемый код (см. раздел **Security** в [An Overview of Managed/Unmanaged Code Interoperability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx)). Другой процесс точно не может залезть в вашу память из-за аппаратных ограничений, и другой домен приложения не сможет, если вы очень явно этого не разрешите.

*Кстати, куча тоже не обычная последовательность блоков — для увеличения производительности сборки мусора, она разбита на две части: для маленьких объектов и для больших объектов.*

Теперь конкретно про ваш код. Вы располагаете два массива по одному и тому же адресу. В .NET размер массива хранится в самом его начале, для него выделяется 8 байт, то есть число типа `System.Int64`. Исходный массив имеет длину 8. Когда вы пытаетесь работать с этим массивом, как с массивом `ulong`'ов, длина остаётся той же, то есть 8, но вот сами элементы становятся больше в 8 раз. Поэтому вы можете прочитать 8 × 8 байт вместо 8.

Но иногда может происходить исключение, связанное с тем, что массив проходит по границе сегмента, выделенного операционной системой, и это будет уже чисто аппаратное исключение. Если вы попытаетесь записать что-то в `ulong` массив, поведение будет непредсказуемым. Каждый блок в куче предваряется служебным заголовком, поэтому с 9-го байта может быть такой заголовок и расположен, соответственно при следующей сборке мусора приложение может упасть.

Comment: Лучший ответ. От постороннего читателя спасибо!

Comment: Вообще, да - там, где у меня это используется, я не только читаю конвертированный массив, но и пишу в него. Думаю, что это не плохо, если не выходить за границы массива (по `ulongs` я иду в цикле от нуля до `bytes.Length/sizeof(ulong)` плюс "хвост" по `bytes` длиной `bytes.Length%sizeof(ulong)`). Стало, однако, интересно - что там за границей массива и чьё оно.

Comment: @i-one, посмотрите в сторону метода [BitConverter.ToUInt64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter.touint64(v=vs.110).aspx). Работать будет чуть медленнее, зато метод безопасный и стандартный.

Comment: BitConverter, насколько я вижу, позволяет читать данные в массиве "по месту", но у него, к сожалению, нет подобного метода, позволяющего _изменять_ данные в массиве (т.е. чтобы разом, а не побайтово, вкатить ulong в 8 байт массива). Впрочем, просто чтение тоже кое-где пригодится.

Comment: Если массив длинных целых нужно конвертировать в массив байт целиком, можно попробовать `ulongArray.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray()`. Это медленнее, чем прямые манипуляции с памятью, но, как я уже писал, это управляемый код, который можно будет запускать везде, потому что он ничего не сломает.

Answer (score 2):

Массив был выделен в управляемой куче. В первой строке вывода виден, собственно, исходный массив байт.

Значит, в остальных строках - случайный фрагмент управляемой кучи.

---

PS не используйте подобные хаки для преобразования, используйте лучше [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)